# Redis: specific sorting results

Tags: sorting, redis

I have data in my table of users ("nickname" field):

```
User Name
username2
username1
UserName
username4
username3
```

I want to sort it like this:

```
username1
username2
username3
username4
UserName
User Name
```

First to have text and numeric order, and then only text.
How can I do this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation: http://redis.io/commands/SORT

Try:

```
SORT nickname
```

Comment: Now sorting works by "sort_*->nickname" and results is good, but not best:
UserName

User Name
username1
username2
username3
username4

Comment: This is some custom sorting rule. I doubt that redis supports this. Why don't you sort it in some programming language from where you are accessing the redis db ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few things you must clear up about the solution:

#### 1) The kind of data structure you will use

Before dealing with `SORT`, you must store the data in some Redis structure. You have plenty of options for this case. Redis native data structures are: hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets and simple key/value.

You could use lists for this, like:

```
lpush mylist "User Name" username2 username1 UserName username4 username3
```

Notice that you have to enclose spaces in values with double quotes.

You could also use sets, **the main difference between sets and lists is that sets only store distinct values** (see the example below, in which a duplicated value is stored once):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd sample_set avalue avalue
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers sample_set
1) "avalue"
```

So with sets, you would go like:

```
sadd myset "User Name" username2 username1 UserName username4 username3
```

#### 2) SORT lexicographically

You will use `SORT`, now when you want to sort lexicographically you must use the `ALPHA` modifier:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sort mylist alpha
1) "User Name"
2) "UserName"
3) "username1"
4) "username2"
5) "username3"
6) "username4"
```

The sorted order for `myset` elements is identical.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sort myset alpha
1) "User Name"
2) "UserName"
3) "username1"
4) "username2"
5) "username3"
6) "username4"
```

So you may have noticed that the order you stated you wanted is not quite equal to the common lexicographic order: **space**, **numbers**, **uppercase letters**, **lowercase letters**  which follows the [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com) order.